# How does hibernate.order_inserts work incase of unexpected order

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am facing a strange issue because of `hibernate.order_inserts`.
Consider the below example

```
@Entity
@Table
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "EMP_SEQ", sequenceName = "EMP_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMP_SEQ")
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String salary;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> address;
}


@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ADD_SEQ", sequenceName = "ADD_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ADD_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ADDRESSID")
    private Long addreessId;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPID")
    private Employee employee;

}
```

Here is my `entitymanager` configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" name="emp"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="emp" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.flushmode">COMMIT</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now according to Hibernate documentation http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/def/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.EventSource%29
Inserts will be ordered the way there are executed.Lets say for instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/batch-context.xml");
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = (EntityManagerFactory) applicationContext.getBean("entityManagerFactory");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Employee kumar = entityManager.getReference(Employee.class, 2l);

        Address kumarAddress = new Address();
        kumarAddress.setStreet("kiev");
        kumarAddress.setEmployee(kumar);

        Employee pavan = new Employee();
        pavan.setName("xyz");
        pavan.setSalary("100000");

        Address pavanAddress = new Address();
        pavanAddress.setStreet("USA");
        pavanAddress.setEmployee(pavan);

        List<Address> emp2Address = new ArrayList<Address>();
        emp2Address.add(pavanAddress);

        pavan.setAddress(emp2Address);

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        entityManager.persist(kumarAddress);

        entityManager.persist(pavan);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();

    }
```

Since insertion of `kumarAddress` is executed  first and since i have enabled `hibernate.order_inserts` ,hibernate should insert both address together.If does so it should fail since  `pavanAddress` is depended on `pavan` which is not inserted yet.

How does hibernate order inserts queries in this case?The above code works fine.But am facing this problem in my project.Hibernate is batching both child inserts together even if parent of child is not inserted.My problem is resolved if disable `hibernate.order_inserts` . I am trying to understand how hibernate works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will notice that your child entities are dependent on the father and will insert that before.

The property for ordering insert come into play when you batch insert: let's say you want to persist 2 parent and 2 childs in this order

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
```

Like this hibernate can't batch properly because statements target different table.

with order_inserts the statement will properly be ordered by table (where possible)
so you are going to get

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not happening in my application.It triggers insert on child tables and batch them

Comment: simple: you are doing B1, A1, B2. Hibernate will notice B1 needs A1 first so it will order accordingly to avoid FK failure (A1, B1, B2)